# (SpringBoot v3.0, SpringSecurity v6.0) How do I specify specific endpoints to be unsecured/secured?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have been trying to solve this problem for days, gave a different error when I compile. So I understood that .antMatchers have been deprecated and .requestMatchers should be used instead.

However, when I used it, it gives the error of "Spring security method cannot decide pattern is mvc or not spring boot application exception". I saw this article on stackoverflow, Followed the fix but to no avail.

I managed to get it out without compilation error but the endpoints are still fully secured and I am unable to specify which endpoints I want to be unsecured. Everytime the server starts, I get a 403 for each endpoint i go to.

This is my current code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {


    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc(HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) {
        return new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector)
                .servletPath("/api/v1");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                .requestMatchers(mvc.pattern("/auth/**")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            // stateless authentication 
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

EDIT: JwtAuthFilter

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Middleware jwtService;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, 
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, 
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            final String jwtToken;
            final String userEmail;

            if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                return;
            }

            jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
            userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);

            if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

                if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                    );
                    authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                    );
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Handle any exceptions here
        }

        // Continue the filter chain
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please remove jwtAuthFilter handing out jwts to browsers is dangerous and insecure as jwts lack the security features that cookies have. The tutorial you have followed has no idea how security works.

Comment: `/api` path is from the application.properties, i mean `server.servlet.context-path="/api"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more information, how you can avoid this problem i recommend you to check it on **Mitigations** part of `README` and also how there was explain:

*Separating the servlet path when constructing an MvcRequestMatcher is important to ensure that the request is correctly matched.*

[Mitigations](https://github.com/jzheaux/cve-2023-34035-mitigations)

**UPDATE**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        http
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/api/v1/**")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/error/**")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            // stateless authentication 
            .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        System.out.println("Test");
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Also remove from `application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1
```

Comment: nothing difficult, i set `AntPathRequestMatcher("/error/**")).permitAll()` just to see `/error` endpoint, also we use it for `servletRequest` aka( classes annotated with `@RestController`, that return json body as a response.)

Comment: I see. so can I say that because it was actually blocking the "/error/" endpoint hence i wasnt able to 'break through' the secure endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to use any HandlerMappingIntrospector args and mvc stuffs,

just try this:

```
 @Bean
       public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
            http
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(
                            (request)->
                                    request
                    .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
            http
                    .sessionManagement(
                            (session)->
                                    session
                                            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
            http
                    .authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    
        }
       }
```

[Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html)

Comment: Hello Kabil, thank you for your answer. However, if i do not specify the type of Matcher im going to use. I will get a compilation error. 


"
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityFilterChain' threw exception with message: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).
"

Comment: @codingNewb that's something new to me! Thank u for the infor.